# Python class member definition syntax is inconsistent?

Tags: python

```
>>> class A:
...     a = 0
...
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.a = 1
>>> print a2.a
0
```

there are 2 'a' int belong to a1 and a2 respectively

```
>>> class B:
...     a = A()
...
>>> b1 = B()
>>> b2 = B()
>>> b1.a.a = 2
>>> print b2.a.a
2
```

there is only one 'a' object shared with b1 and b2. I know it could init in `__init__` to make it belong to object rather than class, but why int 'a' in first example are not shared?

Comment: What behavior do you observe that has lead you to this incorrect conclusion?

Comment: it's both members of class. if you want to create object member then use `self`. `self.a = 2`

Comment: ok, I revised my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. Both `a` and `b` are class attributes. If you want an instance attribute, set `self.whatevername` in the `__init__` method:

```
class A(object):
    b = B() # Class attribute
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1 # Instance attribute
```

When you do `a1.a = 1`, you create a new `a` instance attribute that hides the old class attribute.
Similarly, if you had tried `b1.a = A()` instead of `b1.a.a = 1`, you would have created a new instance attribute on `b1` instead of modifying the class-level `A` instance's attributes.
If ints were mutable and you tried mutating `a1.a` - let's pretend they have a `screw_with` method - then `a1.a.screw_with()` would screw with the class-level `a` int.